# Do the banded operators check the invariant subspace problem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, open-problems, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded operators.

**[Invariant subspace problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem)**: Let $T \in B(H)$. Is there a non-trivial closed $T$-invariant subspace?

**Remark**: This problem is known for the Banach spaces in general, but still open for an Hilbert space.

Let $(e_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an *orthonormal basis*.
**Definition** : $T \in B(H)$ is **banded** if $\exists r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(Te_{n}, e_{m})\ne 0 \Rightarrow \vert n-m \vert \leq r$.

**Remark**: A *banded* operator is a thick generalization of a diagonal operator.  It's also a finite sum of finite product of (*orthonormal*) weighted shift operators (which check obviously the ISP).

> **Question**: Do the banded operators check the invariant subspace problem ?

**Remarks**:

- MO post : [Is there an operator algebraic reformulation of the invariant subspace problem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138070/is-there-an-operator-algebraic-reformulation-of-the-invariant-subspace-problem)
- Here is a question on MSE  : [Is every operator unitary equivalent to a banded operator ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452908/are-all-the-operators-thick-diagonalizable)
  N. Ozawa answered "no" in its comment below (see also sections 16.3 and 16.4 of its book [here](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-88)), because if an operator is unitary equivalent to a banded operator, it generates an exact $C^{∗}$-algebra, however D. Voiculescu gave examples of quasidiagonal operators which don't generate exact $C^{*}$-algebras:  *A note on quasidiagonal operators*, Operator Theory, 1988, 265-274.
- MSE post: [Does an irreducible operator generate an exact $C^{∗}$-algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455949/does-an-irreducible-operator-generate-an-exact-c-algebra).
  C. Eckhardt answered "no" by giving some simple, singly generated and non-exact $C^{*}$-algebras. By simplicity, their irreducible representations are faithful. So, there are irreducible operators $T \in B(H)$ with $C^{*}(T)$ non-exact (and a fortiori non-nuclear).
- An ISP counter-example is necessarily irreducible, but the Voiculescu examples are not :
  MSE post : [Is every irreducible operator unitary equivalent to a banded operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454135/is-every-irreducible-operator-unitary-equivalent-to-a-banded-operator)
  By pooling the answers of N. Ozawa and C. Eckhardt we can also answer "no".

Comment: this is a notoriously open question and your question is extremely difficult to answer

Comment: Is the terminology "quasi-diagonalizable" standard? and is it related to the standard terminology "quasidiagonal"?

Comment: I think your question would be improved if you gave some justification, other than curiosity, for why you hope this restricted class of operators could suffice to test the ISP

Comment: You are probably aware of this already, and I haven't checked anything at all here, but recently it has been established that the hyperinvariant subspace problem admits a reduction to a class of quasidiagonal operators: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123604001211

Comment: Regarding my last comment, the appropriate notion of "quasidiagonal" is discussed in section 5 of http://www.unf.edu/~shamid/Paper%202.pdf

Comment: @YemonChoi : the terminology "quasi-diagonalizable" is not standard, and not related to "quasidiagonal". The class of operators I defined is a thick generalization of the diagonal operators, in particular, it contains the shift. Now in section 5 of Jon Bannon's last link, a quasidiagonal operator is a sum of a block-diagonal and a compact operator, but the shift is not of this form.  To avoid confusion, I will replace the name by "thick-diagonal".

Comment: @YemonChoi:   
Now a thick-diagonal operator is not a curiosity, for two reason : firstly, it's a generalization of the weight shift operators, to be more precise, it's a finite sum of finite product of weight shift operators. However, a weight shift operator checks obviously the ISP. Secondly, I don't know yet whether or not every operators are unitary equivalent to thick-diagonal operators (i.e. thick-diagonalizable, see my MSE post).

Comment: @JonBannon : thank you for the links containing the standard definition of "quasidiagonal" operators. As I write in my previous comments, the class of operators I defined differs, and I replace the name by thick-diagonal. These papers are about the hyperinvariant subspace problem (HISP). If (HISP) is true, then (ISP) is also true, but I don't know if the converse holds.

Comment: It is not known whether all weighted BILATERAL shifts have NTIS, and all weighted bilateral shifts are thick-diagonal.

Comment: @BillJohnson : I don't understand, could you please enlighten me ? The reason of my misunderstanding is the following : a bilateral shift is an operator $T$ in $B(l^{2}(\mathbb{Z}))$ such that $Te_{n} = w_{n}e_{n+1}$, with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $(e_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ an **orthonormal basis** and $w_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$. Let $K_{n} = \langle e_{n}, e_{n+1}, e_{n+2}, ... \rangle $, then $\overline{K_{n}}$ is a closed, non-trivial, $T$-invariant subspace, right ? I trust you, so where is my mistake here ?

Comment: Here is the answer to the question in Remark. People often call such operators "banded operators." The C*-algebra on $\ell_2({\bf Z})$ generated by the banded operators (aka the uniform Roe algebra of $\bf Z$) is canonically isomorphic as $\ell_\infty({\bf Z})\rtimes {\bf Z}$, which is nuclear and has tracial states (coming from invariant means on $\bf Z$). So, any operator which is unitarily equivalent to a banded operator generates an exact C*-algebra having tracial states, which is not the case in general.

Comment: Thank you @NarutakaOZAWA ! I have replaced "thick-operator" by "banded operator". I have find your [book](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-88) on which section 16.3 and 16.4 is about this question. I have written your answer on MSE, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452908/is-every-operator-unitary-equivalent-to-a-banded-operator/453971#453971).

Comment: @Sebastier: Sorry; NTHIS (hyperinvariant).

Comment: "check" = verifie ou safisfait?

Comment: @YemonChoi : "vérifie" seems a better translation. To avoid any confusion, when I say that an operator $T$ checks the ISP, this means that there is a closed, non-trivial, $T$-invariant subspace.

Comment: @Sébastien: first, every C*-algebra has an irreducible representation, and exact C*-algebras with tracial states is a rather restricted class. Second, Voiculescu's counterexamples are for quasidiagonal operators which do not generate exact C*-algebras, and they are not relevant to ISP (in fact they are block diagonal operators).

Comment: +1 Taka. I do not understand why SP thinks exact C-star algebras are relevant. Note that conjugating T with some arbitrary invertible will not affect ISP but will change drastically the C-star algebra generated by the and the VN algebra generated by T

Comment: To clarify this, I posted the question: : [Is there an operator algebraic reformulation of the invariant subspace problem ?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138070/is-there-an-operator-algebraic-reformulation-of-the-invariant-subspace-problem).

Comment: @YemonChoi : just a remark about your comment <<will change drastically>> : if $T \in B(H)$ is a counter-example of the ISP, and $P$ invertible, then $W^{*}(T) = W^{*}(P^{-1}TP) = B(H)$. So it's *invariant* under conjugation by invertible (so not at all *drastically* different...). Now what about $C^{*}(T) $ and $ C^{*}(P^{-1}TP)$ ? always nuclear or exact ?

Comment: @YemonChoi: I have edited some answers about nuclearness and exactness.