# Is there an operator algebraic reformulation of the invariant subspace problem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded operators.

**[Invariant subspace problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem)**: Let $T \in B(H)$. Is there a non-trivial closed $T$-invariant subspace?

**Remark**: This problem is known for the Banach spaces in general, but is still open for an Hilbert space.

The **ISP** is an *operator theoretic* problem, and I ask here about an *operator algebraic* reformulation.

A counter-example $T \in B(H)$ of the ISP is a fortiori an **irreducible operator**, i.e. $W^{*}(T) = B(H)$. But of course the converse is false : there are many irreducible operators which are not counter-examples of the ISP (for example the unilateral shift).

**Conclusion** : the von Neumann algebras don't *see* the ISP, because the property to be a counter-exemple of the ISP can't be encode in $W^{*}(T)$.

Is there a property $P$ of $C^{*}$-algebras verifying : $T$ is a counter-example of the ISP iff $C^{*}(T)$ is $P$ ?

Perhaps the $C^{*}$-algebras are also not relevant for the ISP, I don't know...
 In this case, is there a class of operator $*$-algebras which is relevant for the ISP ?

Perhaps the operator $*$-algebras are also not relevant for the ISP...
Is there a class of operator algebras (non necessarily self-adjoint), which is relevant for the ISP ?

> Is there an operator algebraic reformulation of the invariant subspace
>   problem ?

To be more precise, is there a class $\mathcal{C}$ of operator algebras and a property $\mathcal{P}$, such that the algebra $\mathcal{C}(T)$ of class $\mathcal{C}$ generated by $T \in B(H)$, is $\mathcal{P}$ iff $T$ is a counter-example of the ISP ?

Comment: If $T \in B(H)$ is an ISP counter-example then $W^{*}(T) = B(H)$, but what's the list of all the properties of $C^{*}(T)$ ? Conversely, if $C^{*}(T)$ verifies this list, is $T$ an ISP counter-example ?  (idem with $W(T) = \overline{\langle T \rangle }^{wot} $).

Comment: It seems that you are looking for properties of C^*(T) which are, in particular, invariant under replacement of T by any S^{-1}TS. Perhaps you could obtain a more focused question by adding some specific properties you think might be relevant? (E.g. commutativity is not such a property, and I suspect nuclearity is not.)

Comment: @YemonChoi : intuitively, the question is to know if the $C^{*}$-algebras *see* the ISP. If $T$ is an ISP counter-example, then $T$ is irreducible, noncompact-commuting, nonnormal and with spectrum strictly continuous. We could deduce some properties of $C^{*}(T)$. Unfortunately, this list here is not sufficient, because there are weight shifts checking this list **and** the ISP. It's the purpose of my post about banded operators, if they all check the ISP, we could then add *non-banded* to the list, and there is still not a candidate checking this completed list.

Comment: Now, perhaps, the $C^{*}$-algebras do not *see* the ISP, and so it would be more relevant to investigate $C(T)$ or $W(T)$ which is known to be *reductive* : it's an important property, because  RAD implies ISP (see Mike answer below).

Comment: I think your last comment is more likely to be the correct reading. All these vague and hopeful questions about the STAR-algebras generated by T seem far less convincing than approaches via non-self-adjoint op alg theory, for the reasons hinted at in my previous comment

Comment: @YemonChoi, you wrote: "if $T$ is an ISP counter-example, then so is $S^{−1}TS$ with $S$ bijective, however $C^{*}(T)$ and $C^{*}(S^{−1}TS)$ can be highly different". I would be very interested by an explicit proof of "the $C^{*}$-algebras don't see the ISP" (as for the $W^{*}$). Do you have one ? If so, please write it as an answer.

Comment: See this post : [Is there a proof that the $C^{∗}$-algebras don't see the invariant subspace problem?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138523/is-there-a-proof-that-the-c-algebras-dont-see-the-invariant-subspace-prob)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the weakest form of your question ("Is there a class of operator algebras relevant to the ISP?"), there is the "reductive algebra problem," which is not quite of the form you're asking for but is, I think, in the same spirit. An algebra of bounded operators on Hilbert space is called *reductive* if it is WOT-closed, contains 1, and every invariant subspace for the algebra is reducing for the algebra. The *reductive algebra problem* asks if every reductive algebra is self-adjoint. It is known that a "yes" answer to RAP implies a "yes" answer to ISP. (In fact, if I am not mistaken, a "yes" to RAP actually implies a "yes" to the hyperinvariant subspace problem.) I am not sure about the status of (ISP implies RAP).  If you haven't already, you might want to look at the book "Invariant Subspaces" by Radjavi and Rosenthal.

Comment: Thank you @MikeJury. A counter-example $T \in B(H) $ of the ISP is of course non-normal. If $R\in B(H)$ is normal, there is a [theorem](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pjm/1102994515) due to Sarason : $\overline{\mathbb{C}[R]}^{wot}$ is a $∗$-algebra if and only if $R$ is reductive, i.e. every closed invariant subspace $K \subset H$ of $R$, is a reducing subspace.  If I'm not mistaken, the RAP generalizes this theorem to every operator.

Comment: In particular, if $T$ is a counter-example of the ISP, then $\mathcal{A} = \overline{\mathbb{C}[T]}^{wot}$ is reductive because its invariant subspace are $\{0 \}$ and $H$ (obviously reducing the algebra). So if the RAP is true, $\mathcal{A}$ is self-adjoint, in particular, $T^{*} \in \mathcal{A}$, but $\mathcal{A} \subset \{ T\}'$ and $T$ is non-normal, so contradiction, and ISP is true.

Comment: So if $T$ is a counter-example of the ISP, $\overline{\mathbb{C}[T]}^{wot}$ is a reductive and non-selfadjoint algebra.  For the converse, if  $\mathcal{A} = \overline{\mathbb{C}[T]}^{wot}$ has no non-trivial invariant subspace, then it's reductive and also non-selfadjoint algebra (because if $\mathcal{A}$ selfadjoint, then it's irreducible and so $\mathcal{A} = B(H)$, contradiction with the commutativity of $\mathcal{A}$). So the question is : does $\mathcal{A} = \overline{\mathbb{C}[T]}^{wot}$ has no non-trivial invariant subspace, implies $T$ a counter-example of the ISP ?

Comment: [Radjavi and Rosenthal - Invariant subspaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65574-6).