# Is there a proof that the $C^{*}$-algebras don't see the invariant subspace problem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

This post is an appendix of this [one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138070/is-there-an-operator-algebraic-reformulation-of-the-invariant-subspace-problem).

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the algebra of bounded operators.

**[Invariant subspace problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem)**: Let $T \in B(H)$. Is there a non-trivial closed $T$-invariant subspace?

**Hypothesis** : The ISP admits a negative answer, i.e., there are ISP counter-examples.

**Definition** : A category $\mathcal{S}$ of operator algebras **see the ISP** if $ \forall T, T' \in B(H)$ with  $\mathcal{S}(T) \simeq \mathcal{S}(T')$:
$$
T \text{ is an ISP counter-example} \Leftrightarrow T' \text{ is an ISP counter-example }
$$

**Proposition**: The category $W^{*}$ of von Neumann algebras, **doesn't see** the ISP.
**proof**: Under the previous *hypothesis*,  let $T \in B(H)$ be an ISP counter-example. Then $T$ is irreducible,  i.e.,  $W^{*}(T) = B(H)$.  But there are many irreducible operators checking the ISP, for example, the **unilateral shift** $S$. So $W^{*}(T) \simeq W^{*}(S)$, $S$ checks the ISP and $T$ not. $\square$

This post asks about an equivalent result for the category of $C^{*}$-algebras :

> Is there a proof that the category of $C^{*}$-algebras *doesn't see* the
>   ISP ?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{S}(T)$ the operator algebra generated by $T$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathcal{S}(T)$ is the operator algebra (of category $\mathcal{S}$) generated by $T \in B(H)$. Just a precision, the $C^{∗}$-algebras and von Neumann algebras are here **separable** (the categories $C^{∗}$ and $W^{∗}$).  If we can prove that $C^{∗}(T)$ is a Cuntz algebra (with $T\in B(H)$ an ISP counter-example), the result should follow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C*-algebras don't see the ISP. The operators $T\in B(H)$ and $T\oplus T\in B(H\oplus H)$
generate isomorphic C*-algebras, but the latter clearly has non-trivial invariant subspaces.
To have both operators in the same Hilbert space, pick isometries $v_1,v_2\in B(H)$ with orthogonal ranges that add up to $H$. Then
$$
T\mapsto v_1Tv_1^*+v_2Tv_2^*
$$ 
is an injective *-endomorphism of $B(H)$ that maps $T$ to an operator with non-trivial invariant subspaces.

Comment: Thank you Leonel ! This map is continuous for the main topologies of operators algebras (norm-topology, weak-topology, strong-topology...), and this argument runs also without a $\star$-structure (on the algebra), so that it shows that no category of operator algebras *see the ISP*. Is it right ?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: I guess so. Though I'm not sure that the question cannot be made more interesting by tweaking it a little.

Comment: A generic way for tweaking a question, is to improve it by excluding the counter-examples. Here we can improve the definition of "see the ISP" by : $\forall T, T' \in B(H)$ with $\mathcal{S}(T) \simeq \mathcal{S}(T') $ and  $T' \ne v_{1} T v^{*}_{1} + v_{2} T v^{*}_{2}$ (with $v_{1}$, $v_{2}$ as in your answer), then : "$T$ is an ISP counter-example" $\Leftrightarrow$ "$T'$ is an ISP counter-example".  Is this what you thought? Else what do you suggest ?